# Iron router + observechanges = repeated observechanges handler calls?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm attempting to use observechanges with iron router but they don't seem to be compatible at all.

```
Router.route('/gaming', {
            waitOn: function() {
              return Meteor.subscribe('chat', function() {
                window.chatmessagesCache = new ReactiveVar;
                chatmessagesCache.set([]);
                return chat.find().observeChanges({
                  added: function(id, doc) {
                    var tmpArr;
                    tmpArr = chatmessagesCache.get();
                    tmpArr.push(doc);
                    return chatmessagesCache.set(tmpArr);
                  }
                });
              });
            }
```

If I leave the route and come back to it, observechanges begins being handled as many times as I've navigated away and returned, for each new record.  What's the deal?

If I use [subs manager](https://github.com/meteorhacks/subs-manager) it works as expected, but I don't understand why Meteor.subscribe inside waitOn is so cache/subscription unaware when it ALREADY gets called multiple times per load.  Why!?  I can't decipher what's causing this behavior at all.

Also, what I'm trying to accomplish is simple.  I want to let chat messages that the user's client has received remain on the page even if the chat cursor is no longer publishing them (I'm publishing the last 10 chat messages)

Answer (score 1):

Iron router has reactivity built in, which means when something inside your route function is invalidated, it will repeat the function as well as anything reactive with a `Router.current()`. These unexpected invalidation runs are a primary reason why folks made the exodus to flow router.

To solve this, you'll want to abstract your code away from the router. You can leave the sub, but I'd suggest you remove the sub's callback from the `waitOn` and move it into an `onRendered` callback. If you don't want the history loaded in chunks, you can first do a `var collectionCount = chat.find({},{reactive:false}).count()` on how many docs are in the collection & then in the `added` callback you can do something like `if (++currentCount === collectionCount) /* add stuff */` to add al the records to the history when it reaches the last record.

On a bigger picture level, consider eliminating the observeChanges & just do an `#each` over the chat collection in spacebars to show your messages. Fewer cycles, cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

Iron router just has no management of observations you created yet it manages subscriptions itself, hence the multiple additions.

I figured this out by using a window level variable to check if I'm observing.  Even in cases when the subscription is unhooked by iron, if I go back and never re-add the handler,  the original observation hook still runs (!).  ALSO, if you navigate away and drop the subscription, the handler is no longer called--which is the behavior I want in this scenario (This is all very insane behavior but at least it's now predictable to me )

This is caused by the fact that subscriptions != collections and the API for observations doesn't seem to expose any metadata, unfortunately, so I don't know how the iron router maintainers would account for this.  Not to mention you return iron router a subscription, not a collection.

@Matt K if you were correct, this would always be an infinite loop (which admittedly I had a bunch of while trying to solve this) but the posted code is adding too many handlers, not looping indefinitely.  Thanks for the post though.

This is what I settled on

```
Router.route('/gaming',
      waitOn: ->
        Meteor.subscribe('chat', ->
          window.chatmessagesCache = new ReactiveVar(chat.find().fetch().reverse())
          if !window.chatListening
            window.chatListening = true
            after = chat.find().count()
            chat.find().observe(
              added: _.after(after + 1,(doc) ->
                tmpArr = chatmessagesCache.get()
                tmpArr.push(doc)
                chatmessagesCache.set(tmpArr))
              changed : (id, doc) ->
          ))
```

I really just wanted to test out a pattern of locally "disconnected" documents.  I still may use subs manager because it keeps subscriptions and their handlers alive without rerunning them constantly (which was rerunning the sub handler, which was adding multiple observations)